# MechWarrior (1st Edition) vs MechWarrior (2nd Edition) Character Stats / Conversion

Tags: character-creation, conversion, attributes, battletech, mechwarrior-4e

BattleTech & MechWarrior used to be 'mini combat' & 'rpg' respectively; and have gone through various versions; changing core aspects of the game & how the math works.  In MechWarrior, here's what I remember:

```
Characteristics             Attributes
Athletic        18-Bld-Ref  Build
Physical        18-Itn-Ref  Reflexes
                            Intuition
Mental          18-Itn-Lrn  Learn
Social          18-Itn-Cha  Charisma
```

But in some of the older "scenario/lore" books, I find reference to the following "stats":

- bod
- dex
- lrn
- cha
- pib
- htk

Which **source** book(*s*) describes the above stats?  (note: I know the "scenario/lore" books 'use/list' them, but they take it for granted "what they mean" and/or "how they're used".)

How are the two related?..  20+ years ago, I vaguely remember that one of the many books had 'how to convert' in the back; but it's been too long so perhaps I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On page 49 of Mechwarrior (***2nd** Edition ~ FASA 1641 MechWarrior 2nd Edition*) is a section titled "Adapting Original MechWarrior", which in itself is a partial answer to the question above...

It discusses the Attribute (*bod, dex, lrn, cha*) & Skill/Advantages conversions (*or guidelines wrt Intuition, as that did not exist in 1st Edition.  In addition, it 'hand-waves' the removal of most Inborn Advantages & Disadvantages; the latter of which would unbalance converted characters*.)

PIB in 1st Edition, is 'Personal Initiative Bonus', and starts on pg 70 of Mechwarrior (***1st** Edition ~ FASA 1607 MechWarrior: The BattleTech Role Playing Game*)...  it is a combination of Dex, Lrn, & Tactics, Leadership.  This is replaced by a simpler roll + REF system in 2nd Ed (*with ITN being a tie-breaker*) on page 52 of Mechwarrior (***2nd** Edition*).

Separately, HTK (*which in 1st Edition worked like D&D Hit Points*) is replaced with a location based damage system in 2nd Ed (*similar to how mech damage is allocated*.)  Damage resilience is now based on the Body stat, with the utilization starting on page 49 of Mechwarrior (***2nd** Edition*).